# Dynamic subobject memory allocation Clang++ vc g++

Tags: c++, g++, clang

I have a doubt in the process of dynamic memory allocation for subobject. 
Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct S
{
    long l;
};

struct V
{
    long d;
};

struct A
{
    int a;
};

struct B : A, S, V
{ 
    void * operator new(std::size_t t)
    {
        cout << t << endl;
        return ::operator new(t);
    }
};

B *b = new B; // Prints 12 for g++ and 24 for clang++.

int main()
{
    b -> a = 23;
    b -> l = 3L;
    b -> d = 52L;
}
```

[demo for g++](http://ideone.com/aV5y5s)

[demo for clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be25065a4b71362b)

The results of `g++` and `clang++` are different. But because of `8 + 8 + 4 = 20`, I expected that `20` will be printed. Could you explain the point of such values of parameter, passing to the operator new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when the code is compiled using g++ the size of long is equal to the size of int and in turn equal to 4.
When the code is compiled by clang then the size of long is equal to 8 while the size of int is equal to 4. clang appends the structure with 4 bytes that it would be alligned by 8 that is according to the allignment of the type long.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you are using 32 bit mode by default for gcc and 64 bit mode for clang. The size of a `long` is sufficient to represent, at least, 32 bit. This wil use 4 bytes on for `int` and `long` on typical 32 bit system. On 64 bit systems `int` and `long` tend to use 64 bit, i.e., 32 bits. You might want to print the `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)`. Even if `sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)` it is likely that the type would be padded to a multiple of `sizeof(long).`